# Initializing a thread in a static block?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, jvm

If I start a thread in a static block. Will the jvm wait for the thread to finish before it loads the class?

```
static {
    System.out.println("static block");
    DataRetrievalThread t = new DataRetrievalThread();
    t.run();
}
```

The reason I'm trying this is because 
I want to retrieve data from a server and it's taking way too long to get it. So to persist the data I want to retrieve it and store it in a file so that when the client asks for it - it does not need to make the call to the server to get the information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I start a thread in a static block. Will the jvm wait for the thread to finish before it loads the class?

Uh.  Yes and no and NO.

1. First off, your code is not forking a thread.  So as it is written it *will* hold up the class construction although technically the class is "loaded" before the `static` section runs.  That's because you are executing the `run()` method directly in the current main thread.  If you want to fork the thread then you should call `t.start();`.
2. If you actually fork the thread with `t.start()` then no, the thread will run in the background and will not hold up the class initialization.
3. You really should *not* be doing something like this.  It's a tremendously bad pattern.  If you explain what you are trying to accomplish, we should be able to *really* help.

If you are trying to pre-load data into your program then you should just run the load part early on in `main()` and don't park it in a `static` initializer in a class.  But if you are running it in the main thread, holding up the program, I don't see why this is any faster then making the request on demand.

One thing to consider is to fork (with `t.start()`) a background thread to load the data and then have a class which holds the data.  If the thread finishes in time then it will have pre-loaded the data.  When the program needs the data, it should call the class to get it.  If the thread hasn't finished it could do a `countDownLatch.await()`.  When the thread finishes the download it could do `countDownLatch.countDown()`.  So you will get some parallelism.

Something like:

```
public class DataLoader {
    private volatile Stuff data;
    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    // start the thread, called early in main()
    public void init() {
        // you pass in this so it can call setData
        DataRetrievalThread t = new DataRetrievalThread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    // called from the DataRetrievalThread
    public void setData(Stuff data) {
        this.data = data;
        latch.countDown();
    }
    public Stuff getData() {
        if (data == null) {
            latch.await();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `run()` you execute the method in the current thread, so after that the class will finish loading. You need to call `start()` to run the method in a new thread.